# RxSwift smoothen Observable values

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

```
// Transform a stream of [Int] where the chunks are received in bursts into a continuous stream of metric values
//
//   Example:
//
//      Original:      <-----[Int32][Int32][Int32]------------------[Int32][Int32][Int32]----------------[Int32][Int32][Int32]----------->
//      Transformed:   <-----Int32-Int32-Int32-Int32-Int32-Int32-Int32-Int32-Int32-Int32-Int32-Int32-Int32-Int32-Int32-Int32-Int32-Int32->
//
```

Notes:

- Observable receives and Array of 250 points every 1 second
- Want to smoothen this to distribute the points over that 1 second
- Send them out to be used by the UI for graphing

---

RectiveSwift implementation:

extension SignalProducerProtocol where Value == [Double], Error == BioDemoError {

```
func startAndFlattenBurstIntervalChunks(periodInMs: UInt, minTimeDeltaBetweenBurstsInMs: UInt64 = 500) -> (Signal<Double, NoError>, Disposable) {

    let (individualValueSignal, individualValueObserver) = Signal<Double, NoError>.pipe()
    let compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    let valueBuffer = MutableProperty<[Double]>([])
    var timeOfLastChunk = Date() //first one doesn't matter

    func addChunkToBuffer(chunk: [Double]) {
        let currentTime = Date()
        valueBuffer.modify { buffer in

            // Only flush current buffer if this is the first chunk of a burst
            let shouldFlushCurrentBuffer = currentTime.millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch - timeOfLastChunk.millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch > minTimeDeltaBetweenBurstsInMs

            if(shouldFlushCurrentBuffer) {
                buffer.forEach(individualValueObserver.send)
                buffer = chunk
            } else {
                buffer = buffer + chunk
            }

        }
        timeOfLastChunk = currentTime
    }

    func sendFirstBufferValue() {
        valueBuffer.modify { buffer in
            if let firstValue = buffer.first {
                individualValueObserver.send(value: firstValue)
                buffer = buffer.tail()
            }
        }
    }

    let periodTime = DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(Int(periodInMs))

    compositeDisposable.add(
        timer(interval: periodTime, on: QueueScheduler())
            .map { _ in () }
            .startWithValues(sendFirstBufferValue)
    )

    compositeDisposable.add(
        self
            .flatMapError { _ in SignalProducer<[Double], NoError>.never }
            .startWithValues(addChunkToBuffer)
    )

    return (individualValueSignal, compositeDisposable)

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would *.flatMap()* arrays to individual items (*.flatMap { Observable.from(iterable: $0)}*) and *.zip()* them with a timer observable (like *Observable.interval(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)*) while making sure that backpressure does not get in the way. See http://rxmarbles.com/#zip

Answer (score 0):

You can write the exact same implementation from ReactiveSwift using `Relay` instead of `MutableProperty`. I would also potentially look into [window()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/window.html).

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to store your "irregular" data to some kind of buffer and then read the stored elements out at a fixed interval of time. Here's what I've come up with:

```
struct Smoothener {
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    static let elementsPerInterval: Double = 10
    static let intervalSize: Double = 1
    let smoothedResultObservable: Observable<Int>

    // Generates bursts once per interval, test data
    // Can be any pattern you want
    let sourceObservable = Observable<Int>.create { observer in
        var number = 0
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: Smoothener.intervalSize, repeats: true) { timer in
            for _ in 0...Int(Smoothener.elementsPerInterval) {
                observer.onNext(number)
                number += 1 // For easier testing incrementing number
            }
        }

        return Disposables.create {
            timer.fire()
        }
    }

    // Time counter
    let timerObservable = Observable<Date>.create { (observer) -> Disposable in
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: Smoothener.intervalSize / Smoothener.elementsPerInterval, repeats: true) { timer in
            observer.onNext(timer.fireDate )
        }

        return Disposables.create {
            timer.fire()
        }
    }

    init() {
        // Fills the buffer from the generated data
        var currentBuffer: [Int] = []
       _ =  sourceObservable
            .buffer(timeSpan: Smoothener.intervalSize, count: Int(Smoothener.elementsPerInterval), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: { (buffer) in
                currentBuffer = buffer
            })

        // transform buffers to integers when the timer fires
        smoothedResultObservable = timerObservable
            // only proceed if the buffer is filled
            .filter({ _ in currentBuffer.count == Int(Smoothener.elementsPerInterval) })
            .enumerated()
            .map({ (index, observable) -> Int in
                return currentBuffer[index % Int(Smoothener.elementsPerInterval)]
            })
    }
}
```

And print smoothened results:

```
    _ = Smoothener().smoothedResultObservable
        .subscribe(onNext: { (number) in
            print(number) // numbers get output at a fixed interval
        })
```

`sourceObservable` could be something you pass to the `Smoothener` instead of generating values internally in the struct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since I'm using an extension, I fitted the solution to use that as my sourceObservable. I'm running into ```cannot assign value of type 'Event<[[Int32]]>' to type 'Int[32]' ``` on the subscribe after .buffer.... My sourceObservable is from extending ```extension Observable where E == [Int32]```

Comment: I would only need that ```.buffer....```to ensure that the currentBuffer gets flushed when either a certain time has passed or the number of points are filled